# Is there any way to set cookie to all the sub-domains of a domain (Domain=.site.com) but exclude just 1 domain?

Tags: http, web, https, http-headers

We're in a situation where we're pointing one of our sub-domain (sub.site1.com) to a third party application (app.site2.com) through a CNAME record. I don't want to send user cookies to their servers. Is there any way to set cookies to all our sub-domains except for sub.site1.com? Please help.

I've tried different variations of Set-Cookie with Domain specification.

Comment: The cookie with domain `.site1.com` won't be sent in request to `app.site2.com` -- these are 2 different domains.

Comment: sub.site1.com is pointing to app.site2.com through a CNAME record as I mentioned. For browser sub.site1.com is a valid subdomain to do Domain=.site1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible.

According to [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) (the RFC that describes cookie), the [syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) of cookie domain is:

```
domain-av         = "Domain=" domain-value
domain-value      = <subdomain>
                       ; defined in [RFC1034], Section 3.5, as
                       ; enhanced by [RFC1123], Section 2.1
```

Then, according to [RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5) and [RFC1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13), the domain that can be used in cookie does not support any complex syntax. There is no way to exlude one subdomain while support all others.